# C program that checks if a number is palindromic

Tags: c, palindrome

I wrote this C program which compiles just great, but when I enter an input it never stops running and when I force stop it, it says "floating point exception (core dumped)". It is basically a function implemented in a bigger program but we dont need that in this case. So whats the deal?

This is the block of code. I wrote the main function just to test the isPal function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int NumOfDigits(long long x) {
    int sum = 1;
    while (x / 10 != 0) {
        sum ++;
        x = x / 10;
    }
    return sum;
}

int isPal(long long x) {
    int f, c, front, back, sum;
    sum = NumOfDigits(x);
    
    c = pow(10,(sum-2));
    front = x / pow(10,(sum - 1));
    back = x % 10;
    f = 1; 

    while (x != 0 && f == 1) {
        if (front == back) {
           x = (x / 10) % c;
           c /= 100;
           sum -=2;
           front = x / pow(10,sum);
           back = x / 10;
        } else {
           f = 0;
        }
    }
    if (f) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

int main() {
    int f;
    long long x;
    scanf("%lld\n", &x);
    f = isPal(x);
    if (f) {
        printf("yes"); }
        else { printf("no"); }
}
```

Comment: Converting the integer to a string would have been easier.

Comment: Single step through the program with your debugger and find the line where you are dividing by zero.

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Change `scanf("%lld\n", &x);` to `scanf("%lld", &x);`.

Comment: When you ask about a problem, you should include the exact text of input that reproduces the problem. Generally, you need to provide all information that other people need to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Using floating point calculation for this is wrong in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

If you are testing with a single digit input, then `sum` is one, and `c = pow(10,(sum-2));` sets `c` to zero, since 10<sup>−1</sup> = .1, which becomes zero when converted to `int` for assignment to `c`. Then `(x / 10) % c` divides by zero.

With other numbers with an odd number of digits, `c` will start non-zero, but `c /= 100` will eventually change it to zero, again causing `(x / 10) % c` to divide by zero.

You need to change the code to avoid this division by zero.

Additionally, some low-quality `pow` implementations return inaccurate results even when the mathematical result is exactly representable. For example, `pow(10, 0)` may return a number slightly less than one even though it ought to return one. You can correct for that by using `round(pow(10, i))` instead of `pow(10, i)` (or `lround` or one of the other rounding functions).

However, when testing whether an input numeral is palindromic, it is often preferable to merely read the numeral as a string and test the characters directly, without converting them to a number.

Answer (score 1):

The answer from @EricPostpischil explains the divide-by-zero problems very well. This answer is just to show an alternative approach.

The maximum number of digits in a `long long` is fairly small so it's not a problem to calculate all the digits and store them in an array. Then the high/low digits are easy to compare.

Something like:

```
int isPal(long long x) 
{
    int digit[32]; // long long has less than 32 digits
    int cnt = 0;
    while(x != 0)
    {
        digit[cnt] = x % 10;
        ++cnt;
        x = x / 10;
    }
    
    int low = 0;
    int high = cnt - 1;
    while (low < high)
    {
        if (digit[low] != digit[high]) return 0;
        ++low;
        --high;
    }
    return 1;
}
```